# Events not spanning days

Tags: fullcalendar

I have implemented fullcalendar and it is working fine apart from 2 issues (I'll raise the second one in another question).

I can't add an image as I don't have the reputation! So to explain what I mean, I have an event that runs from 10am, July 3rd to 10am July 5th.  When viewed by month it only displays on the 3rd July and does not span the 4th or 5th.

Here is my implementation code;

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events:function(start, end, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'webservices/wsEvents.asmx/GetEventsBetweenDates',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            data:  formatCalendarDates(start, end),
            success: function (doc) {
                var events = [];
                $.each(doc.d, function() {
                    var duration = GetDuration($(this).attr('StartTime'), $(this).attr('EndTime'), true);
                    var allday = moment.duration(moment($(this).attr('EndTime'))-moment($(this).attr('StartTime'))).days() >=1 ? true : false;
                    //    duration.toLowerCase().indexOf("day") >= 0 ? true : false;
                    events.push({
                        title: replaceCharacter($(this).attr('Title'), "/u0027", "'"),
                        start: $(this).attr('StartTime'),
                        id: $(this).attr('ID'),
                        description: replaceCharacter($(this).attr('Description'),"/u0027","'"),
                        allDay: allday,
                        locationID: $(this).attr('Location'),
                        location: replaceCharacter($(this).attr('LocationName'), "/u0027", "'"),
                        duration: duration
                    });
                });
                callback(events);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //     debugger;
                ShowError("Error: " + textStatus);
            }
        });
    },
    theme: true,
    header: {
        left: 'prevYear,prev,next,nextYear today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    buttonIcons:{
        prevYear: "ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-w",
        prev: "ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-w",
        next: "ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-e",
        nextYear: "ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"
    },
    editable: false,
    allDaySlot: true,
    allDayDefault: false,
    firstDay: 1,
    timeFormat: {
        month: "H:mm",
        week: "",
        day: ""
    },
    weekNumbers: true,
    weekNumberCalculation: "iso",
    weekMode: "liquid",
    weekNumberTitle: "Wk",
    defaultView: "month",
    firstHour: 0,
    buttonText: {
        today: 'today',
        month: 'month',
        week: 'week',
        day: 'day'
    },
    columnFormat: {
        month: 'ddd',    // Mon
        week: 'ddd d/M', // Mon 9/7
        day: 'dddd d/M'  // Monday 9/7
    },
    eventClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        DisplaySingleEvent(date, false)
    },
    eventMouseover: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
        $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer')
    },
    eventMouseout: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        $(this).css('cursor', 'default')
    },
    eventRender: function (event, element) {
    },
    viewDisplay: function (view) {
    }
});
```

Can anyone see from my code what I've done wrong?

Thanks

Terry.

Comment: what is exactly not working? please minimize your code to show exact problem and/or create jsfiddle for it. SO is not "review me code" website.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. For future questions: please give the version of fullcalendar you used and I agree with @fsw that you need to minimize the amount of code you post. This should include the relevant custom functions you call (you didn't give the code for `GetDuration` for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Educated guess: specify `end` in the events array. You give `duration` but this is not a [standard attribute](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) according to the spec.

Comment: Thank you Mabi!  I hadn't realised that somewhere along the line I had deleted the end parameter.  that solved it thanks.